# iOS - NSMutableDictionary reverting to previous state?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, nsmutabledictionary

I'm trying to make a "Delete" button on an "Edit Item" page, which when pressed will go back and remove the relevant entry in an `NSMutableDictionary` on the previous page, and then update the tableview list of entries.

It starts with an IBAction method on the "Edit Item" page, which basically does nothing but feed the key to be deleted back to the controller for the previous page:

```
- (IBAction)deleteItem:(id)sender {
    [_parentController removeItemWithDeleteButton:[_mainFactoidTextField text]];
}
```

which is where the action actually starts (on the list page):

```
- (void)removeItemWithDeleteButton:(NSString *)key {
    [_currentItemsDict removeObjectForKey:key];
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

At the start of that method, `_currentItemsDict` has 8 objects, which drops to 7 after `removeObjectForKey:` is called.  Then it pops off the top ViewController, which is the "Edit Item" page, returning us to the list of entries.

Then when that method is done, the breakpoint immediately jumps to:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    NSArray *tempArray = [NSArray arrayWithArray:[_currentItemsDict allKeys]];
    NSArray *sortedArray = [tempArray sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)];
    _currentItemsArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:sortedArray];

    [_tableView reloadData];
}
```

But by the first line of `viewWillAppear:`, `_currentItemsDict` has reverted back to 8 objects.  Everything works fine from then on, but it's all working with the original 8 entries, meaning that nothing got deleted.

From my limited experience with these sorts of things (I'm definitely still a beginner), I'm going to guess this has something to do with the `popViewControllerAnimated:` method, but I cannot figure out what.  I've heard distantly of certain variables being stored in different ways that might make them come back as an earlier version of themselves, but I haven't wrapped my mind around the concept.  Or maybe it's something else entirely, I don't know.  All I can tell is that `_currentItemDict` has 7 objects, and then one line later it has 8 again.

Can anyone help out a new guy, and explain where I'm going wrong?  Or if it's easier, can you suggest a better solution for removing an entry in an `NSMutableDictionary` from a different ViewController?  (Code samples and tutorial links are much appreciated, as I'm currently just noobish enough to sometimes be unable to translate theory into practice on my own!)

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Maybe you remove object from copy of `_currentItemsDict` and not from the original?

Comment: Are you sure that you're operating on the same array? Is `_currentItemsDict` on the edit page the same array of the "top viewcontroller"? From your code it seems that you're operating on different intsances.

Comment: The first method listed (`deleteItem:`) is the only one on the Edit page, the rest are on the list page. The way I've been using (and maybe this is the problem) to communicate back to the previous page is to store the list page controller as a property in the Edit page during the segue (i.e. `[[segue destinationViewController] setParentController:self];`), and then calling a method back into that `_parentController` property as needed. That could be a separate instance (I'm inexperienced with that), but the same method works successfully to add a new entry, just not to delete an existing one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you know how properties work in Objective-C 2.0? I would declare a property in your parentViewController to contain your _currentItemsArray, declared as a strong reference.

```
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSMutableArray *_currentItemsArray;
```

Also, set a weak property in your childViewController (the one you push to for deletion)

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) NSMutableArray *parentItemsArray;
```

Set the property on the childViewController upon push

```
childViewController.parentItemsArray = self._currentItemsArray;

[self.navigationController pushViewController:childViewController animated:YES];
```

Remove the item inside the array within childViewController instead of calling a method on your parentController

```
[self.parentItemsArray removeObjectAtIndex:indexOfKey];
```

Doing this, you don't have to sort the array again in viewWillAppear. Instead, just ask the tableView to reloadData

Does any of this make sense?

It also may be wise to include your logic inside cellForRowAtIndexPath, numberOfRowsInSection and the other tableViewDataSource methods.

Comment: You're awesome, thank you!  I actually had a similar setup a while back (passing the full dictionary down to the child, removing the entry within the child's copy, etc) but I abandoned it for the current setup.  My only question (and the reason I abandoned that process earlier) is this: how do you get the updated dictionary (after the deletions have been made on the child page's copy) back up to the parent?  Won't that leave you with an Edit page that has the most current info, but a List page that has no idea that anything changed?

Comment: Aha!  WEAK was the key.  I'm going to go learn more about strong vs weak now.  Thanks again!

Comment: Do you understand now? When you "pass the dictionary down to the child" you don't need to "get an updated copy back to the parent". That's what strong/weak does. The "parent" object has a `strong` relationship to this object. There is no "copy" being made. It did take me a little while to understand this too but once it makes sense, that makes all the difference.

Comment: Also FYI: there is a `copy` option in the property constructor, you can use it in place of `strong` or `weak`. Doing this creates a new copy of the object. Use this for strings and things that you want to be sure are NOT mutated or changed. If you opt to `copy` a property, you would indeed have to pass it back if you needed to update a previous object with any changes.

Comment: Nice tip, I can already think of times I'd use that.  Thanks!